# Sencha Touch/ExtJS: how do i dynamically define a model?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I would like to dynamically define models to handle data from a data store.
I have a web service that returns different JSON structures (eg. `field_1:"val1"`  or `field_1:"val1 field_2:"val2"` or `field_1:"val1"...field_n:"valn"`). I've seen that for using

```
Ext.regStore("UserStuffStore",{
        model: "myModel",
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: rl,
            headers: {
                'Accept' : 'application/json'
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    });
```

I need to specify a model. In this case, I need to see data structures before defining the model. How can I solve it?

Surely I can make two different calls to the web service (the first to get the data structures, the other to get data), is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Not tested. I hope it helps:

```
var fields = [{
    name: 'id',
    type: 'int',
    useNull:true
}]; //this can be obtained dynamically

var model = {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: fields
};

Ext.define(name, model);
```

Also see: [Sencha forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?130997-Dynamic-Model)